# HTML: Can I safely ignore "Element 'input' cannot be nested inside element 'button'" warning?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's the HTML:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="return false"/></button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><input type="checkbox" onclick="return false" disabled="disabled"/></a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><input type="checkbox" onclick="return false"/></a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><input type="checkbox" checked onclick="return false"/></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically it's a Bootstrap dropdown example.

I need this to a table column filter, to be able to filter either by true, false, or no filter.

Never mind the JS logic here.

- the checkboxes are "presentation only" - they should not function as checkboxes, they serve as checkbox symbols. I don't have time and resources to provide vector graphics / specialized fonts here. I want that as simple as possible. Paste that into JSFiddle and include Bootstrap to see how it looks.
- all checkboxes must be displayed correctly on modern desktop and mobile browsers

It should not break anything.

The Visual Studio however warns me about `input` inside a `button`. I know, it's against HTML standard, but I tested it on Edge, Chrome and FireFox and it works. Is there a catch here?

I know, a checkbox (or any other input) BEHAVIOR inside a button element is undefined. But if I don't want them to function, just display - it should be OK? Well, I even taken care about the undefined behavior: if one browser decided to allow checkbox to function inside the button, I explicitly set `onclick` attribute to just return `false`.

So, would you leave it or not? Is there a better way to present such filter? Maybe a free web-font playing nice with Bootstrap? A web-font having symbols like checked box, unchecked box, star or any other symbol representing "I don't care if checked".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you shouldn't ignore the warning. It's invalid HTML to place interactive elements (such as `<input>` elements) inside of `<a>` links or `<button>` elements, and creates accessibility issues.

Some additional considerations:

- Are your dropdown menu items acting like checkboxes? If a user clicks one, does the state of the checkbox change? If so, you should use `<input type="checkbox">` elements *instead* of links.
- Conversely, if your dropdown menu items are acting like links (taking the user to new content), you shouldn't make them visually look like checkboxes.

If you do find a semantically justifiable reason for needing `<a>` links or `<button>` elements that look like checkboxes, you should use an `<img>` for the box part of the checkbox instead of co-opting another element that isn't semantically appropriate.

Comment: Sure, I just changed buttons and links to `span` elements. Bootstrap doesn't care. More problematic is using checkboxes. I don't want them to work, but well... For now let it be, I styled them to look cool, I'll change them to some nice web font symbols in the future. I just need to find the right font. So bad free subset of Open Iconic doesn't have anything like that.

Comment: @Harry If you're using the `<button>` to toggle the visibility of the dropdown, it should remain a `<button>` for accessibility purposes—and you should replace the `<input>` inside it with a non-interactive element.

Comment: I eventually used Material Design Font for "checkbox" graphics. It's the same Chrome uses. Looks great, and I received positive feedback from users (they knew where to click to filter the table). Now I went to a quite different CSS hell of vertical alignment of things ;)